# How to access full URL to uploaded files in Cognito Forms with JSON WebHook

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm experimenting with Cognito Forms and the JSON WebHooks. The problem I'm running into is how to access images (or any file) uploaded with a form. I need to get the image's URL to download it, but the JSON data received only has an "Id" field, and the file name, but no URL.

How can I use the Id to get the full file URL?

This will be done automatically by a custom application so I need it to work programmatically, NOT as a manual ("go to this page and click here") process.

Sample of JSON data received from image upload widget looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "ContentType": "image/png",
        "Id": "F-RvLAskaPGomphWSa4LFsXk",
        "Name": "Screen Shot 2015-03-08 at 1.34.19 PM.png",
        "Size": 1044716
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports direct file access via [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/cognito-forms/) integration, but not through JSON webhooks.  We will be enhancing our integration options over the next few months and this will definitely address this.  In the meantime, please see if Zapier will meet your integration needs.